# Where do i find server name in Parallel Plesk Panel

Tags: asp.net, hosting, connection-string

I deployed my website in Parallel Plesk Panel and created database but i can't see any help about ***Where do i find server name? and how to create connection of my application and database?***

Comment: try 'localhost', or ask your provider.

Comment: Yes, you need to ask your hosting provider. It available on your CP--> database. You will see the details of your database server name.

Answer (score 0):

You could find it via: Settings -> Databases -> Database Hosting Preferences -> Database Servers.
Also you could try it with "localhost" or 127.0.0.1.